# Is there a python sdk to get the list of vnet peering in azure?

Tags: azure, vpc-peering

Is there a python sdk command to get the vnet peering details in azure along with the necessary input variables.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't find the sdk but found a az network command which gave me the outcome
"az network vnet peering list -g MyResourceGroup --vnet-name MyVnet1"

In python you have to do something like

```
from azure.cli.core import get_default_cli
get_default_cli().invoke(['network', 'vnet', 'peering', 'list','-g','rsg001','--vnet-name','vnet001'])
```

Keep into mind I already have the az account login in powershell.

Comment: Also this might be helpful    https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-network/azure.mgmt.network.v2020_04_01.operations.virtualnetworkpeeringsoperations?view=azure-python    and  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-network/azure.mgmt.network.v2020_04_01.models.virtualnetworkpeering?view=azure-python